# Meteor changing form value upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to change the values of some input fields **only once upon page being loaded**. For example submit_date_year should be current year, so 2017 right now.

My HTML

```
<template name="trip_html">

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover rsk-tbl vScrollTHead">
<tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_day" type="text" placeholder="Day"/>  </td>
       <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_month" type="text" placeholder="Month"/>  </td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_year" type="text" placeholder="Year"/>  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

My JS

On page load function

```
Template.trip_html.rendered = function(event, template) {

     event.target.submit_date_year.value = 'test'; // DOES NOT WORK
      console.log('Template onLoad');

};
```

However, I cannot use event.target.submit_date_year in that on load function, for some reason...
But it works in events, once I click 'submit' button

```
Template.trip_html.events({
"submit .add-trip": function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var day = event.target.submit_date_day.value;
var month = event.target.submit_date_month.value;


var year = event.target.submit_date_year.value;

var car = event.target.submit_car.value;
var b = event.target.submit_b.value;
var a = event.target.submit_a.value;
var dist = event.target.submit_dist.value;

if(empty(day) || empty(month) || empty(year) || empty(car) || empty(b) || empty(a) || empty(dist)){
return false;
}

if(!isNumeric(day) || !isNumeric(month) || !isNumeric(year) || !isNumeric(dist)){
    return false;
}

if(day.startsWith("0"))
day = day.replace("0", "");

if(month.startsWith("0"))
month = month.replace("0", "");

if(year.startsWith("0"))
year = year.replace("0", "");

console.log(day, month, year, car, a, b, dist);
Meteor.call('addTrip', day, month, year, car, a, b, dist);

event.target.submit_a.value = event.target.submit_b.value;
event.target.submit_b.value = '';
event.target.submit_dist.value = '';


},
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are passing an event parameter in the onRendered Callback. Therefore, you can't select the DOM element via `event.target`.

try to give the element a certain class in the markup and replace the line `event.target.submit_date_year.value = 'test'; // DOES NOT WORK`
with something like:

```
$('.year-input').val() = 'test';
```

The html line:

```
<td><input class="form-control input-lg year-input" name="submit_date_year" type="text" placeholder="Year"/></td>
```

You can delete the 'event' parameter from the rendered callback now.
Hope, I could help.

Comment: That jquery code doesn't work, and ends up giving me an error Unexpected token. I even tried the following jquery, that gives me the same error:     var year = $(".year-input", ".add-trip").value = "test2";

Comment: Try to use this `document.getElementsByClassName('year-input');` instead of the jquery line. You can also put it in a variable and output it to the console for debug purposes. For e.g.: `let el = document.getElementsByClassName('year-input');` and then `console.log(el);` If you get the element selected it should works somehow.

Comment: with  var val = document.getElementsByClassName('year-input');  console.log(val); I do get to my element, it finds it but  val.value = "TEST"; does nothing, nor does ClassName('year-input').value = "TEST"; Darn you BlazeJS (MeteorJS)

Comment: I don't if that helps but I recognized that I call the function differently: `Template.myTemplateName.onRendered(function() { //my function;  });`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because you aren't using the `onRendered` function properly. You are also trying to access the input using an event object which doesn't exist because there is no event.

Try:

```
Template.trip_html.onRendered(function () {
  $('input[name="submit_date_year"]').val('2017');
});
```

**EDIT**

You can just use HTML to achieve this too if you don't need the data to be dynamic.

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="submit_date_year" type="text" placeholder="Year" value="2017"/>
```

Comment: Error in given second line sadly :( . client/main.js:73:2: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression (73:2), commenting out:  $('input[name="submit_date_year"]').val() = '2017' removes the error.

Comment: @AleksD Sorry I was being stupid and made a mistake in my code. Check it now and try that.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but still.. doesn't work.. if I add console.log("On load") in that function I do get the output, but.. the value remains empty, sadly :|

Comment: Ok, Let's just test this by trying just targeting all inputs for a sec.
Change the jQuery to: ```$( "input" ).val( "test" );```. If it works you should see 'test' in all the inputs

Comment: @AleksD You can just use HTML to achieve this too btw